# add sql WHERE statement to select new ID:s in database (asp / sql)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to update a website where there's new ID's for different damage groups. All the new ID's start after ID 139. In SQL the statement to get the new groups are simply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DamageCode 
WHERE ID >= 139
```

However, I want to implement the same statement in my ASP code and in the method that fetches the current damage groups. Here's the current method for it:

```
public List<DamageCode> GetDamageCodes(int codeId) 
{
    var list = new List<DamageCode>();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("spDamage_GetDamageCodeComponents", Connection);

    try 
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeId", codeId);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
        {
            foreach(DataRow i in dt.Rows) 
            {
                var model = new DamageCode();
                model.DamageCodeId = Convert.ToInt32(i["ID"]);
                model.DamageCodeName = i["Swedish"].ToString(); // DamageCode WHERE ID >= 139
                list.Add(model);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SqlException ex) 
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        Connection.Close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Basically: I want to update this method and add some a statement similar to the SQL statement, so that `i["ID"]` only will fetch ID's after number 139.

Any ideas on how to do this directly in this method?

I've tried adding a new sql similar to:

```
string query = 'SELECT * FROM DamageCode WHERE ID >= 139';
```

But, I am unsure where to use the query later in the method.

Comment: Why not modify the `spDamage_GetDamageCodeComponents` procedure to include your requirements; IMHO this is where you *should make changes*. Otherwise, you could do `linq` and only select the rows you need once its filled and then go through only those rows.

Comment: Side note: `throw new Exception(ex.Message);` This line will reset the stack trace for the thrown Exception. You should keep it because it makes it much easier to find where an exception originated from. You can do this by passing the Exception instance to a new exception in the constructor `throw new Exception(ex);` or keep the original exception after logging or whatever using `throw;`. Both of these methods preserve the stack trace.

Comment: Also **do not** cache the connection object. Create it when you need it, and dispose it (and command and reader objects) with `using` blocks

Comment: @zaggler you were right i found the stored procedure and simply changed the sql statement there, thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change to stored procedure

```
"spDamage_GetDamageCodeComponents"
```

in the database and alter the procedure to only show `ID where ID >= 139` , this is much simpler than to change the whole method